# Easier way to code multiple .hide() .show() jquery for menu items

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm building a website that doesn't have much content. So I'm only having one real url which is example.com. Then I have 7 jump links for the other 7 "pages".

For example, when someone goes to example.com, it will .show() example.com content, and .hide() all the other 7 "pages" of content. Then if the user say clicks on a "menu" item with the url jump link of example.com/#about-us, it will then .hide() example.com content and keep all the other content still hidden, but hen .show() example.com/#about-us content.

So the whole website stays the same on any new jump(menu) link clicked, the only thing that changes is the div content area.

I have jquery that looks like this

```
$('#jumplink1').click(function(){
    $('.jumplinks').hide();
    $('#jumplink1').show();
});

$('#jumplink2').click(function(){
    $('.jumplinks').hide();
    $('#jumplink2').show();
});

$('#jumplink3').click(function(){
    $('.jumplinks').hide();
    $('#jumplink3').show();
});
```

And so on.... Is there a simpler way to write this jquery?

Also, if I may ask, what are the negatives to using this type of website structure? I know the big positive is that it loads practically everything the first time, so then when a user clicks on a new "menu" link it happens instantly. But is this bad for like SEO or anything else?

Comment: Your jQuery code makes no sense to me. `°L°` : `Click on #jumplink1 = SHOW #jumplink1` huh?

Comment: oh im sorry. all the jump links are shown, it's the content that gets hidden and then only the content of the jump link clicked that gets showed... sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have links (the jumplinks) with a class `jumplinks` and an uniquie id like `('link1', 'link2', ...)` and the content on the site is grouped in containers having a class `content` an id similar to the one of the jumplinks but with postfix `_content ('link1_content', 'link2_content', ...)`. If you dont have a setup like thi you should definitly think about how you set it up and give us info about it here.
Using this setup you would know which link should show which content.
The code for showing would be the following:

```
$('.jumplinks').click(function(){
  $('.content').hide();

  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#" + id + "_content").show();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. you were right, I didn't set it up efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a class instead of ID here. Have a class 'jump-class' to all the div elements you specified.
 #jumplink1, #jumplink2, #jumplink3, and so on...

And use the following function.

```
jQuery('.jump-class').on('click', function(){
 jQuery(".jumplinks").hide();
 jQuery(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click a link grab the href attribute with

```
.attr('href')
```

then you have the ID of the div you'd like to show and assuming the sections are all siblings you can then do:

```
$($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings().hide()
```